# Delete file if another file does not exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dependencies

I've searched quite a bit on this topic but can only find "delete if file or another file exists" which is not what I need...

Windows 7 from a batch file or command prompt:

Search a specific directory and if any .edl files exist, delete them only if an indenticaly named .ts file does not exist.

The files themselves need no special consideration (not hidden, not in use, have no odd permissions etc), and don't care about size etc

Cheers,
RLW

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%a in (*.edl) do if not exist "%%~na.ts" echo(del "%%a"
```

batch line to be executed from the directory in question, possibly by `pushd "required dir"` before the `for` line and `popd` after (to return to the original directory)

Note that suggestion uses `echo(del` to simply show the proposed deletion. **check first**, then change `echo(del` to `del` if the command is correct.

Comment: Thanks so much, wow, quick response!